# Output-Grid via PowerShell for all Inbound Windows Defender Firewall Rules

Tags: windows, firewall, powershell-5.0

I have a PowerShell script, that works but what I'm having problems with is getting an output grid like an excel sheet.

Here is the code:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule |
    Where-Object {($_.Profiles -band [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetSecurity.Profile]::Domain) -or ($_.Profiles -eq [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetSecurity.Profile]::Any)} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $portFilter = Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_
        $_ | Select-Object -Property `
            Name,
            DisplayName,
            DisplayGroup,
            Profiles,
            Direction,
            @{n='Protocol'; e={$portFilter.Protocol}},
            @{n='LocalPort'; e={$portFilter.LocalPort}},
            @{n='RemotePort'; e={$portFilter.RemotePort}},
            @{n='RemoteAddress'; e={(Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_).RemoteAddress}},
            Enabled,
            Profile,
            Action
    }
```

How do I get the output to a grid format where the it shows it output like an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `| Out-GridView` to the end:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule |
    Where-Object {($_.Profiles -band [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetSecurity.Profile]::Domain) -or ($_.Profiles -eq [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetSecurity.Profile]::Any)} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $portFilter = Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_
        $_ | Select-Object -Property `
            Name,
            DisplayName,
            DisplayGroup,
            Profiles,
            Direction,
            @{n='Protocol'; e={$portFilter.Protocol}},
            @{n='LocalPort'; e={$portFilter.LocalPort}},
            @{n='RemotePort'; e={$portFilter.RemotePort}},
            @{n='RemoteAddress'; e={(Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_).RemoteAddress}},
            Enabled,
            Profile,
            Action
    } | Out-GridView
```

Looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: wow thanks, I cannot believe I missed something so simple.   THANKS many

Comment: You can also get it in textformat by using | format-table. Do note that if the screen is too small, it will compress the columns until you set the width of your window programatically to more columns. This can be preferred because then you can copy the text instead of having to save it to a file.

Comment: can you advise how I can get just inbound (Direction) rules only.  I tried before the ForEach-Object this:

-and ($_.Direction -eq 'Inbound')} |                                                                                This does not work.
Thanks

Comment: @zerokool000 That should be fine - make sure you have your parentheses right? It should look like `Where-Object {(($_.Profiles -band 1) -or ($_.Profiles -like 'Any')) -and $_.Direction -like 'Inbound'} |`